# find multiple patterns in multiple files bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find multiple patterns (I have a file of them) in multiple differents files with a lot of subdirs.
I'm trying to use exit codes for not outputting all patterns found (because I need only the ones which are NOT found), but exit codes doesn't work as I understand them.

```
while read pattern; do
  grep -q -n -r $pattern ./dir/
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    : #echo $pattern ' exists'
  else
    echo $pattern " doesn't exist"
  fi
done <strings.tmp
```

Comment: It would be useful to show a sample of your file `strings.tmp`. Are you trying to match regular expression patterns or fixed strings? How exactly is the code not working? Please edit your question to provide these details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in bash:

```
while read -r pattern; do
  grep -F -q -r "$pattern" ./dir/ || echo $pattern " doesn't exist"
done < strings.tmp
```

- Use `read -r` to safely read regex patterns
- Use quoting in `"$pattern"` to avoid shell escaping
- No need to use `-n` since you're using `-q` (quiet) flag

Comment: yeah, thx, command works by itself, but doesn't work in cycle. I mean it's ok when I take non-exist pattern and check it, but checking it in a loop doesn't work..

Comment: There is no reason for it to not work in loop. Show content of `strings.tmp` in question.

Comment: test.hello
test2.world and similar strings on each line

Comment: ok, i found, the problem was in dots in strings, which are interpreted as a special regexp symbol. just added -F flag for this

Answer (score 1):

@anubhava's solution should work. If it doesn't for some reason, try the following

```
while read -r pattern; do
 lines=`grep -q -r "$pattern" ./dir/ | wc -l`
 if [ $lines -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $pattern " doesn't exist"
 else
    echo $pattern "exists"
 fi
done < strings.tmp
```